# add row using each word in a string that is separated by underscore

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyr, stringr

I have a long vector of strings, which are all composed of five substrings per string separated by underscore symbols:

For example, here's two elements in the vector of strings:

```
"land_somewhat_crop_produce_b.tif"
"marine_something_fish_meat_a.tif"
```

I want to create a dataframe composed of these substrings.

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| land | somewhat | crop | produce | b |
| marine | something | fish | meat | a |

Using regex pattern matching, how can I extract each substring between each underscore and create a dataframe using these substrings for each row?

Comment: You could do `data.frame(orig=c("land_somewhat_crop_produce_b.tif", "marine_something_fish_meat_a.tif")) %>% tidyr::separate(orig, into=paste0("col", 1:5))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do:

```
read.table(text = sub("\\.tif$", "", data), sep = "_")

      V1        V2   V3      V4 V5
1   land  somewhat crop produce  b
2 marine something fish    meat  a
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data <- gsub(".tif","",data)
data.frame(do.call(rbind,strsplit(data,"_")))
```

gives,

```
      X1        X2   X3      X4 X5
1   land  somewhat crop produce  b
2 marine something fish    meat  a
```

**Data:**

```
data <- c("land_somewhat_crop_produce_b.tif","marine_something_fish_meat_a.tif")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` :

```
data <- data.frame(col = sub('\\.tif$', '', data))
splitstackshape::cSplit(data, 'col', sep = '_')

#    col_1     col_2 col_3   col_4 col_5
#1:   land  somewhat  crop produce     b
#2: marine something  fish    meat     a
```